# How to extend a media query with a class

Tags: media-queries, extending

I try to switch the display mode via javascript.

Assuming i have the html element with a class "display_mobile" i tried:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), html.display_mobile {
/* mobile mode definitions */
}
```

but this does not works.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not much into Media queries, but aren't they specifically designed to avoid doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this. Media queries do not allow to use selectors in condition.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    html.display_mobile .any-definition {}
}
```